# How to request a FastCGI application from html page?

Tags: perl, apache, fastcgi, fedora

I am new to Fast CGI. I am using Fedora 15, apache server and Fast CGI with perl.

According to me the concept is something like the fastCGI process will be running as a server process. So how to invoke this continuously running process.

I want Fast CGI program which will read username and password and respond back as success or fail.

Can you please help me with this..

plz correct me if  i m wrong..

Comment: FastCGi works just like CGI as far as clients are concerned. Do you have trouble finding out how to configure FastCGI? Do you have a CGI script which works like you want it to?

Answer (score -2):

Look at the examples that come with apache and fastcgi